# PHP Get browser and OS by user-agent string

Tags: php, function, variables, browser, user-agent

Before thinking that this question is spam and has already been asked, please read.

I need to get the OS and Browser from an user agent and have them in a variable. E.G.

```
$browser = "Chrome Vxx.x"
$os = "Windows 10"
```

I know you could use the get browser function in php, but I need to extract the browser and os of a user-agent that is stored in a database. So I don't want to get the os and browser of the user viewing the page. I am not sure how to do that, maybe some of you could help me. The ideal form would be to get a function like:

```
$os = get_os_from_useragent($stored_useragent);
$browser = get_browser_from_useragent($stored_useragent);
```

Where `$stored_useragent` is the user agent from the database. (already determined)
It would also be great if you would somehow be able to do this without 3rd party classes or other things like that.

Thanks!

Comment: Getting things from a database with PHP is PHP/MySQL 101. Have you taken any tutorials?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @JayBlanchard I think his question is: "How/what string operations do I have to perform on the useragent string to retrieve the OS from it?" and is not about retrieving it from the DB. But of course I am just guessing here.

Comment: You think @Xatenev? OP said, *"Where $stored_useragent is the user agent from the database"*

Comment: @JayBlanchard — Exactly. They have successfully extracted the UA string from the database and stored it in the variable `$stored_useragent`. They want to know how to analyse it.

Comment: @Xatenev is right. Sorry for not saying this in the post, but $stored_useragent is already determined. I am only interested in the analysis of the user-agent string.

Answer (score 1):

You're already aware of the existence of `get_browser`, so it would be sensible to read [the documentation for it](http://php.net/get_browser) in the hope of finding a clue to how to go about doing a related thing.

There you will see the list of arguments the function takes.

> user_agent
>
> The User Agent to be analyzed. By default, the value of HTTP User-Agent header is used; however, you can alter this (i.e., look up another browser's info) by passing this parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure if the URL changed, or if it was never correct, but the correct link is https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: @Randy — The link in the answer works (and isn't specificly to the English version of the documentation).

Comment: It does seem to work now. It didn't work when I wrote that comment.